# Are Foldable and Traversable replacement for Uniplate?

Tags: haskell

I have a kind of minimal language (sort of parser for CISCO-like CLI) that have parser described below. The parser should be serializable to JSON, that's why not Parsec or Attoparsec.

I need a sort of completion tree for those commands, i.e for each prefix there are should be all possible sub-commands. `Cp` type describes basic command structure, i.e the whole language has type `[Cp]`.

For building a completion tree I have to traverse the `Cp` type recursively and build all possible `(Prefix, [Completion])` pairs.

I know how to do this manually. I know how to do this with uniplate (para should work).  The question is: are Foldable/Traversable modern replacement for Uniplate, should I implement this using one of them?

For me it seems that types of `Traversable` doesn't match my case.  What about `Foldable` ? Should I use it or uniplate is still current and solution for cases like this?

```haskell
type Str = Text

data Command = Command Prefix CmdArgs
               deriving Show

type Prefix  = [Str]
type CmdArgs = [CmdArg]
type CmdArg  = (Str,Str)

data Cp =  P Str              -- single token prefix
         | Arg Str            -- arbitrary string or atom
         | B Cp Cp            -- branch: first or second
         | S Cp Cp            -- non-empty sequence of items
         | O Cp               -- optional sequence
         | Discard Cp         -- discards result of nested parser
         | N                  -- null parser, parses nothing
         deriving (Generic,Show)
```

Comment: Can you show what your uniplate code does?

Comment: Actually,  it seems that here acceptable "Evaluation" chapter from Uniplate manual, i.e. if I have to handle each case separately, uniplate is not applicable. Therefore, I have to write the recursing code manually or implement Foldable if I need to re-use this.  But not idea, how to write Foldable/Traversable for this ```Cp``` type.

Comment: Well, both Foldable and Traversable apply to type constructors not concrete types. That is, `Maybe` is foldable, but not `Maybe Int`. So, at the very least you have to add a type parameter to `Cp`, e.g. `data Cp a = ...`. If you show what goes on in your recursion I can give you a more complete answer.

Comment: `Control.Lens.Plated`  from `lens` is also an alternative to Uniplate, based on lensy traversals: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html

Comment: Here the approximate code:
https://gist.github.com/voidlizard/28168c5666eee25e2c4afe4681a982e0#file-dictforcommand-hs

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at your code I now doubt that either Foldable or Traversable will help.

As I mentioned in the comments, both are classes on type
constructors - i.e. types of kind `* -> *`, so you would
have to add a type parameter to `data Cp`, i.e.:

```
data Cp a =  P a
          |  Arg a
          |  B (Cp a) (Cp a)
          ...
```

But even if you did that, neither class quite fits your problem.

The methods in *Travesable* return another container of the same
type. (Presumably the returned container has the same shape.)

The methods in *Foldable* look more promising, but also won't
work because the your folding function isn't provided any
context as to where the `a` is coming from. That is, it won't
be told if it is coming from a `P` constructor or an `Arg`
constructor.

As mentioned in the [docs for **foldr**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldr), we have this "law"
for `foldr`:

```
foldr f z = foldr f z . toList
```

The `foldr` on the LHS is from the Foldable class whereas the `foldr` on the RHS is the one for lists. So a foldr on a `Cp Str` is equivalent
to a foldr on `[Str]` which clearly shows that you can't treat a `Str`
which came from a `P Str` differently from one that came from an `Arg Str`.